# How to remove borders from a table?

Tags: google-docs

How can I remove all borders from a table I created in Google Docs?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not reflect even the most basic level of effort to understand the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Remove Table Borders

You can remove table borders in Google Docs by setting their width to 0 pt.

1. Right-click on the table and select "Table properties" from the menu
   [image]
2. In "Table properties" set the "Table border" to `0 pt`
   [image]

#### Remove Cell Borders

- You can modify the borders of specific cells by selecting them and using the "Border color", the "Border width", and the "Border dash" tools in the main menu.
  [image]
- These table tools, in addition to cell "Background color" and "Table properties" appear at the far right of the main menu, but only when you are editing table contents or have a cell (or cells) selected.
  [image]
- If the tools remain hidden because your browser window width is too narrow to show all menu items, they can be accessed using the "more" (kebab) menu. 
  [image]

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the table and click to edit the properties:
[image]

Then change the border width to zero:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Table properties" in the current version and the "Border weight" can not be set to "0 pt" any more.

But you can make the lines invisible by changing the "Border color" (Pen symbol) to "Transparent".

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt6A5.png "Table properties > Border weight: 0 px").  Maybe talking about the wrong application.